# intellij - How do I add JProgressbar to the swing palette?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

How do I add JProgressbar to the swing palette?

Comment: please what its Swing palette, and whats JProgressbar to do with Swing palette

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the procedure described in "[Adding GUI Components and Forms to the palette](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/adding-gui-components-and-forms-to-the-palette.html)":

[image: add component]

> Right-click the target group, and choose Add Component to Palette.
>   The [Add Component dialog](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/add-edit-palette-component.html) opens.

You will be able to specify the full class name of the component you want to add.